# Appcelerator / Android: Unable to list second level directories with filesystem

Tags: android, filesystems, appcelerator-mobile

I need help with an application i am working with in Appcelerator Titanium for Android.

I got the following code which allows me to show the first (root) level of the attached SD to the emulator (image sample follows):

```
    /*
 *
 * Dynamic data, 
 * taken from the SD card
 * 
 */

//Get the SD card reference
var dir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory);

//Get the directory listing
var directoryStr = dir.getParent().getDirectoryListing();

//Convert the listing into an array for display in tableview
var directoryArr = directoryStr.toString().split(',');

//Initialize tabledata 
var dirData = [];

for (var i=0; i < directoryArr.length; i++) {

      dirData.push({ leftImage:'/images/folder.png', title: directoryArr[i], value: Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory + Titanium.Filesystem.separator + directoryArr[i], hasChild:true });   

      Ti.API.info(Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory + directoryArr[i]);

};

  //Table view for directories
var tableDirs = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: dirData       
});
```

That outputs this:

[image: Data output using the above code]

The following code should give me the string that lists the directories inside, for example, Images directory in the above image.

```
  tableDirs.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    if (e.rowData.hasChild) {


        //Get the SD card reference
        var secDir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory + '/' + e.rowData.title);

        //Get the directory listing
        var secDirStr = secDir.getDirectoryListing();

        alert(secDirStr);


    };



});
```

But instead, i get this:

[image: Unable to understand how to handle that object]

Returns me an object that i don't know how to handle.

Sometimes if i use  the following code:

```
     var dir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory + '/Images');
```

The directory listing returns me a file 'deploy.json'.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. I'm fairly new to Android development, so i might be missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

getDirectoryListing() returns an array. To view its contents, you'd have to look at the specific item in the array like: **secDirStr[0].toString();**

Try the for-loop below to view its contents:

```
if (e.rowData.hasChild) {

    //Get the SD card reference
    var secDir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory + '/' + e.rowData.title);

    //Get the directory listing
    var secDirStr = secDir.getDirectoryListing();

    for (i=0, max=secDirStr.length; i<max; i++){
        alert(secDirStr[i].toString());
    }
};
```